# Gitkit_ServerException: Error code: 17

Tags: php, google-identity-toolkit

I'm attempting to implement the password reset flow for Google Identity Toolkit with the php sdk. I am able to use the sdk to do everything needed except setting up the mail endpoint which exits with the following error.

Here is the code that generates the exception:

```
try {
    $oobResult = $gitkitClient->getOobResults();
    echo $oobResult['response_body'];
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Exception $e";
}
```

And the exception:

```
Exception exception 'Gitkit_ServerException' with message 'Error code: 17' in C:\...\vendor\google\identity-toolkit-php-client\src\RpcHelper.php:229
Stack trace:
#0 C:\...\vendor\google\identity-toolkit-php-client\src\RpcHelper.php(208): Gitkit_RpcHelper->checkGitkitError(Array)
#1 C:\...\vendor\google\identity-toolkit-php-client\src\RpcHelper.php(179): Gitkit_RpcHelper->invokeGitkitApiWithServiceAccount('getOobConfirmat...', Array)
#2 C:\...\vendor\google\identity-toolkit-php-client\src\GitkitClient.php(371): Gitkit_RpcHelper->getOobCode(Array)
#3 C:\...\vendor\google\identity-toolkit-php-client\src\GitkitClient.php(299): Gitkit_Client->buildOobLink(Array, 'resetPassword')
#4 C:\...\auth\mail.php(14): Gitkit_Client->getOobResults(Array, '192.168.1.1')
```

Does anyone know what this error indicates and how to resolve it?

This function from the readme.md generates the same 'Error code: 17'

```
$gitkitClient->getEmailVerificationLink("emailgoeshere");
```

These functions from the readme.md do work as expected:

```
$gitkitClient->getUserById("useridgoeshere"); 
$gitkitClient->deleteUser("useridgoeshere"); 
$gitkitClient->getAllUsers(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a known issue on Identity Toolkit and is now fixed. Can you go the Google Developer Console and make sure you have the correct send email endpoint in your Identity Toolkit config? Also make sure you put the same send email endpoint in your widget config. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. A friend tried to help me with this, used the same code, in a new project and couldn't duplicate it. I started a new project, used the same code, and was unable to duplicate problem. I wrote that project off as corrupted and don't have ability to test it now.